# AdvancedFilter in Excel gives a good range when there are 2+ unique values, but fails when there is only 1

Tags: excel, vba, filter

In Excel 2013, I have a data set in columns A through Z.  For each distinct values in Column B, I create a new workbook and copy all the A-Z data for those values of B into a master sheet in the new book.  I then create a separate sheet for the data for each unique value of B.

E.g., given:

```
A B C
-----
A X 1
A Y 5
A Z 6
B L 7 
B M 0
B N 1
C X 7
```

I want create:

1. A workbook A.xlsx, with:

   1. A worksheet called A, with all the A records
   2. A worksheet called X, with all the X records within A
   3. A worksheet called Y, with all the Y records within A
   4. A worksheet called Z, with all the Z records within A
2. A workbook B.xlsx, with:

   1. A worksheet called B, with all the B records
   2. A worksheet called L, with all the L records within B
   3. A worksheet called M, with all the M records within B
   4. A worksheet called N, with all the N records within B
3. A workbook C.xlsx, with:

   1. A worksheet called C, with all the C records
   2. A worksheet called X, with all the X records within C

The code I have works great AS LONG AS each major group (e.g., A and B) has MORE THAN ONE minor group.  I.e., it works great for major groups A and B, but it chokes on major group C.  This is the relevant chunk of code:

```
' So now we have the new book with the stage-1-filter data.
' Now let's make a stage-2 filter just like we did with stage-1
WBN.Activate 'This the new workbook
WBN.Sheets(wbval).Activate 'Activate sheet for the 2ndary values
Set sRngFilter = Range("C3", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Filter on this column.  Rows 1-3 are headers, first value is in row 4.
Set sRngResults = Range("A1", Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Once the filter is applied, these are the cells to copy
sRngFilter.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True 'Apply the filter to show the distinct values in column C
Set sRngUniques = Range("C4", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Make a range that refers to the values that are shown when the filter is applied.
```

In the debugger, I get something weird which I hope will be a clue:  When I apply a filter that ends up with multiple values, I get a range that looks reasonable:

```
debug.Print sRngUniques.Address
$C$4,$C$11
```

But when I apply a filter resulting in only-one distinct value, the range looks (to me) like nonsense... it's all numbers:

```
debug.Print sRngUniques.Address
$1:$4,$11:$1048576
```

I have a feeling that if I understood what this range meant, I'd get at the heart of my problem and be able to fix.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $1:$4,$11:$1048576 means the range consists of (rows 1 to 4 and rows 11 to 1048576)

Comment: does sRngFilter have a row count?  if it does check to see if it's only 1 as you can't do the xlup (try it manually you'll see what I mean I hope)    If it is one, don't do the xlup if it is > 1 then do the xlup.

Comment: @xQbert sRngUniques.count gives "Runtime error 6: Overflow"... But despite that, it makes sense:  If the bottom value is the only value, and I try to xlup from there, there there's nowhere to go but the header, which I've excluded.  I can think of one work around:  Let the filter include a header row, and let an empty sheet get created for the header row and then delete it.  Not very satisfying, though.